# Closed graph theorem and convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, closed-graph

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces and let $U\subseteq F$ be a subspace and let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of bounded operators between $E$ and $F$ such that $T_n(E)\subseteq U$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

> If there exists a bounded operator $T:E\to F$ such that $T_n\to T$ in $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ and $TE\subseteq U$, then is the convergence true in $\mathcal{L}(E,U)$ as well?

**My thoughts:** I think the result should directly follow from closed graph theorem, although I do not know how to formally show this. The source of the question above is the following observation:

> Let $A$ be a closed operator on a Banach space $E$ and let $0\in\sigma(A)$ be pole of order one. Then $\lambda R(\lambda,A)$ converges to the spectral projection $P$ as $\lambda\to 0$ in $\mathcal{L}(E,D(A))$.

My teacher said that it is sufficient to show that $\lambda A R(\lambda,A)$ converges to $AP$ in $\mathcal{L}(E)$. However, I wondered if one can alternatively use closed graph theorem?

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, in order for the first question to be a generalization of the second, one should have that $U$ is is equipped with a stronger norm (compared to $F$) under which $U$ is complete.

Comment: Why does $T$ belong to $\mathcal L(E,U)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right. I have added this as an assumption!

Comment: The conclusion is false in general. Consider the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ and $U$ the subspace consisting of sequences with finitely many nonzero terms. Let $(T_nx)_k=x_k/k$ for $k\le n$ and $(T_nx)_k=0$ for $k>n.$ Then $T_n\to T,$ where $(Tx)_k=x_k/k.$ But $T(\ell^2)$ is not contained in $U.$

Comment: @BazyliZuczek I have edited my question to include $T(E)\subseteq U$ as an additional hypothesis.

Comment: In that case what is the difference between convergence in $\mathcal L(E,F)$ and $\mathcal L(E,U)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm confused about that as well. As I mentioned, my teacher said that to show $\lambda R(\lambda,A)\to P$ in $\mathcal{L}(E,D(A))$, one needs to show that $\lambda A R(\lambda,A)\to AP$ in $\mathcal{L}(E)$. But I think that because the range of the spectral projection is contained in $D(A)$, the convergence should just be a consequence of the closed graph theorem?

Comment: I think $D(A)$ should be equipped with the graph norm, which makes the second question different from the first.

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, $D(A)$ is equipped with the graph norm. How does it matter? Doesn't the convergence in $\mathcal{L}(E,D(A))$ still follow by closed graph theorem?

Comment: @modeltheory: You should then state in your question that $U$ is equipped with a different norm (stronger than the one on $F$(?)) such that with this norm, $U$ is complete (?).

Comment: @PhoemueX You're right. I have edited my question.